# Set focus to input element within find method

Tags: javascript

Given a form with error states, when the user hits a submit button, the focus should move to the first field with an error state. I'm able to grab the first instance of a field with an error state using:

```
[...document.querySelectorAll(".form-w1")].find(el => el.classList.contains("error"))
```

but can't get the input field nested in the div to set focus to it.

```js
console.log([...document.querySelectorAll(".form-w1")].find(el => el.classList.contains("error")))
```

```html
<span class="form-w1">
  <label>
    <span>First Name</span>
  </label>
  <span>
    <input id="f1" type="text" required="" placeholder=" ">
    </span>
</span>
<span class="form-w1 error">
  <label>
    <span>Last Name</span>
  </label>
  <span>
    <input id="f2" type="text" required="" placeholder=" ">
    </span>
</span>
```

Comment: What's the point of using `.find` here? Seems like you could just use `.querySelector('.form-w1.error input')`

Comment: The `.find` method returns the first instance of the element that has what you're looking for. This is what I need for my case, so that I can find the first field that has an error class and then trying to set focus to the input element nested in the element.

Comment: `document.querySelector('.form-w1.error input')?.focus();`

Comment: @JLRishe - that works, thanks! If you can post that as an answer, I'll check it off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, there's no need to use `.find()`.

Simply use a selector that fully selects what you're looking for:

```js
document.querySelector('.form-w1.error input')?.focus();
```